# Access s3 with aws-sdk from different vpc in nodejs Ec2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to access a s3 bucket(present in different vpc/account) using STS credentials via aws-sdk in nodejs. However it always shows `Access Denied` message when trying to access

```
  import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    credentials: new AWS.Credentials({ accessKeyId: AccessKeyId, secretAccessKey:
                                       SecretAccessKey, sessionToken: SessionToken })
  });
  const listResult = await s3.listObjects({Bucket: bucketName, Delimiter: '/'}).promise();
  logger.info(JSON.stringify(listResult));
```

with following error

```
Access Denied
at Request.extractError (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:585:35)
at Request.callListeners (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/opt/wmc/node-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

But when i try to access the same if I ssh into that Ec2 instance and use aws cli to access the bucket using this same STS credentials, it works fine

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=SecretAccessKey AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= SecretAccessKey AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=SessionToken  aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket-name
```

Is there any node environment variable or aws-sdk config that's needed to get this cross vpc access working?

Answer (score 0):

So for AWS after import you can set the config for it using the following:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.accessKeyId = ACCESS_KEY;
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = SECRET_KEY;
AWS.config.region = REGION;
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

Another way to do this is to assign a role to your EC2 instance that has access to S3. You can then just reference AWS and you will not need an access token or secret key.

More on the second part here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with missing S3 vpc endpoint policy that needed to be added to the vpc, from which you're trying to access the bucket which is present in different VPC, something like

```
{
 "Sid":"",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Principal" : "*",
 "Action": "s3:PutObject",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-you-need-to-upload-to/*"
}
```